# I can not find the right place to insert ADMOB ad

Tags: android, firebase, admob, main-activity

When I place ads, the app closes!

I made these processes
**app/build.gradle**

```js
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the project has several activities, I put it in **BaseActivity**

```js
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

It also has several xml in the layout, I put it in **activity_entry.xml**

```js
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</FrameLayout>
```

I can not identify what is wrong, the print below shows all activity and xml, the project is also available to anyone who can help

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07IBU.png)
Download the project to help you better: https://mega.nz/#!O481VIiA!OV9_qShNl5H_ALkEx9CZRW-kfhKoCSYw_7fJ0x0R4Ic

Comment: Hi Luiz (I'm assuming that that's your first name), welcome to StackOverflow! Please insert the code into your question instead of posting screenshots as this can improve the readability of your question. _(EDIT: Please also consider make your XML be self-closable. For example: `<RelativeLayout ... />` instead of `<RelativeLayout ...></RelativeLayout>` with no content inside of it)

Comment: This question is too fuzzy and has no real connection to programming. Also, it is not a good practice to post a download link. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: edited and left a bit more understandable